# Else function in python 3.1 not working correctly with blank lines in mac os

Tags: python

Why is this not working?

```
def main():
    while True:
    a = input('Guess: ')
    if a == 5:
        print("yes")
    elif a == 10:
        print('yes')   
    elif a == 20:
        print("no") 




break()




    else:
        print("erro")
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string value.  The string `"5"` is not equal to the integer `5`.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the "break" and Def()
Also review your grammer.